# How to enable hot reload in an Angular/Spring-Boot app using Docker?

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, docker, hot-reload

I'm building a fullstack application using Angular and Spring-boot. Since I've added my app to Docker, it doesn't reload when the code is modified.

Here my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  db:
    container_name: MyApp-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MyAppDB
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    container_name: MyApp-adminer
    image: adminer:4.8.0-standalone
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"

  smtp4dev:
    image: rnwood/smtp4dev:v3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9081:80"
      - "9025:25"

  api:
    build:
      context: ./MyApp-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - backend-data:/app
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./MyApp-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - frontend-data:/app
volumes:
  mysql-data:
  backend-data:
  frontend-data:
```

The Dockerfile of the frontend :

```
FROM node:18 AS development

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g node-pre-gyp
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--poll"]
```

The Dockerfile of the backend :

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS development

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]
```

The volumes are well created when I execute the commande "docker-compose up -d --build", but they don't detect any modification in the code. If I modify the code of a file inside a Docker container, it works well.

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: I'd do this by starting your frontend's dependencies in Docker `docker-compose up -d api`, and then running `npm start -- --poll` on the host (not in a container).  Then you won't need to work around Docker's core filesystem isolation features to simulate a local development environment.

Comment: (The `volumes:` you have for the `api` and `frontend` containers will actively prevent you from seeing any code changes, even if you rebuild the images, and I'd recommend deleting them.)